# Beamer background color title

Tags: beamer

I've got this code to the example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

    \usepackage[brazil]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usetheme{default}
    \usecolortheme{crane}
    
    \hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
    \title{\textbf{Title}}
    \subtitle{Subtitle}
    \author{Author}
    \date{date}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{First and only part}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Frame title}
        Text.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image]

[image]

What I want to do is to change the background color in titles from yellow to black, and the text color from black to white (so it can actually be visible).

Also, how to center the title of all frames in it? (The title in frame/image 2 is all to left, I want to center it and for all the other frames.) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the color, add the line

```
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=black}
```

before `\begin{document}`

And according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365539/centering-titles-when-using-the-beamer-class-in-latex), adding `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]` also before `\begin{document}` centers all frametitles.